# Añadir un elemento a un div sin usar innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Dispongo del siguiente código HTML:

```
<div id="combinacion1">
<input type="text" size="5" class="numPrimitiva" onkeyup="validar(this)"/>
<input type="text" size="5" class="numPrimitiva" onkeyup="validar(this)"/> 
<input type="text" size="5" class="numPrimitiva" onkeyup="validar(this)"/> 
<input type="text" size="5" class="numPrimitiva" onkeyup="validar(this)"/>                     
<span></span>
</div>
```

Me gustaría añadir en el span, un resultado de una variable en Javascript sin utilizar el innerHTML y no se me ocurre ninguna forma de hacerlo sin el innerHTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se por qué no quieres/puedes usar innerHTML, pero ¿puedes usar innerText u outerHTML?

Partiendo de este html (simplemente le añadido un id para encontrar fácilmente el span)

```
<div id="combinacion1">
  <input type="text" size="5" class="numPrimitiva" onkeyup="validar(this)"/>
  <input type="text" size="5" class="numPrimitiva" onkeyup="validar(this)"/> 
  <input type="text" size="5" class="numPrimitiva" onkeyup="validar(this)"/> 
  <input type="text" size="5" class="numPrimitiva" onkeyup="validar(this)"/>                     
  <span id="mi_span"></span>
</div>
```

Lo puedes hacer conn innerText:

```
<script>
  var numero = 33;
  document.getElementById("mi_span").innerText = numero;
</script>
```

o con outerHTML:

```
<script>
  var numero = 33;
  document.getElementById("mi_span").outerHTML = '<span id="mi_span">' + numero + '</span>';
</script>
```

puede que haya más maneras, a lo mejor con alguna de esas dos te vale.